# Multiple Formats with PHP DateTime::createFromFormat()

Tags: php, datetime

Let's say the user can submit their time as strings in one of multiple formats.  Is there any way in `DateTime::createFromFormat()` to specify multiple formats to parse.

Right now I notice if you specify a format, any missing elements cause an error.

For example, lets say I'm accepting both `1h22m34s` and a `21m22s` as valid time strings (the second implies `00h`, but doesn't require it).

The following will throw an error on the second string when seen:

```
   $mytime = `21m22s`;
   echo DateTime::createFromFormat('H\hi\ms\s',$mytime)->format('H:i:s');
```

How can I work to allow it to parse multiple formats?

Or is there another, non-hack way to work with multiple formats?

Comment: createFromFormat doesn't throw an error, it just returns false, but yeah, just create an array of acceptable formats, loop through them until it doesn't fail.

Comment: @JohnConde  ouch! I'm hoping there's another option.  I'm in the camp that exceptions should be exceptional, not part of your expected code flow.

Comment: you can decide which format based on the length of the string,isn't ideal either but I guess it could work

Comment: That's not a date or a time, that's a duration. Trying to shoehorn that into a DateTime object is going to bring you nothing but misery. Parse it yourself and convert it to a number of seconds.

Comment: @Gal in this case length might work, but sometimes the formats are the same length.  Think about something like`12:53:01` vs `12:53 01`  I'm sure along the same lines you could try a regex control logic, but I'm really hoping for something more elegant within the DateTime class.  Who knows, if it doesn't exist maybe I'll create something and issue a pull request to the PHP folks!

Comment: @Sammitch  the examples just an example for the sake of showing the issue.  Imagine needing to accept both `19AUG1975` and `19750819` formats or any other crazy custom string representation someone decide to use as their own custom log pattern.

Comment: I think the risk of having no error but a wrong date is very very high. If you make a nice UI, people won't enter different formats. A solution needs to be applied in the frontend, not in the backend.

Answer (score 4):

I know it's been some time but here is a solution based on @dave 's comment.

```php
$date ='20200702';
$formats = ['Y-m-d', 'Y/m/d', 'Ymd'];
$dateObj = null;
foreach ($formats as $format) {
    if ($dateObj = Carbon::createFromFormat($format, $date)){
        break;   
    }
}
```

If you're using [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/) then here is another solution because the behaviour is slightly different.

```php
$date = '20200727';
$formats = ['Y-m-d', 'Y/m/d', 'Ymd'];
$dateObj = null;
foreach ($formats as $format) {
    try{
        if ($dateObj = Carbon::createFromFormat($format, $date)){
            break;   
        }
    } catch (InvalidArgumentException $e) {
        Log::debug('date', [$dateObj]); // It's null
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing! I was able to use this to help with handling an API call that returns data with various date formats.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just the separators that might vary in the input you can use wildcards to represent them.
`Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d*m*Y', $date);`
will handle any of the following formats, and more.
`$date = '11/6/1990'; $date = '11-6-1990'; $date = '11!6/1990';`